# Developing on plesk

Tags: wordpress, dns, plesk

Trying to figure the best way to develop on plesk.

I would like to develop my wordpress website on a temporary url, and attach the production domain only when I am done developing.

From some reason I'm getting various dns errors, saw a guide referring to change of hosts file but it dosent seem like the perfect solution to me.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create the clone of your WP instance (staging) and use Plesk Git extension for developing this staging WP site. After making all necessary changes on staging non-public clone you can publish it to a production domain to make it publicly available.